# Auto Scroll Page + Close Sidebar After menu item select + Link Menu item with Section Ids(Wordpress - Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a custom sidebar menu...I have one page site with section on it...Every sidebar menu link should be connected to a specific section.I have created the menu but  have two problems:

1) I want to link the menu items with sections ids with the help of jquery.
2) When user click on the menu item inthe sidebar,it should be closed automatically and scroll the page to that section.

I am new to Jquery and wordpress..Please help me to resolve this issue.

**Sidebar Html:**

```
<ul id="primary-menu" class="main-nav" role="menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
        <a href="#quote" data-level="1">
            <span class="menu-item-text">
                <span class="menu-text">Instant Quote</span>
                <i class="underline"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li> 
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
        <a href="#ethos" data-level="1">
            <span class="menu-item-text">
                <span class="menu-text">Ethos</span>
                <i class="underline"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>             
</ul>
```

**Here is my Sidebar:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give your section specific id like `<section id="quote">`

Then in your main.js write something

```
$('.menu-item').find('a').click(function(){
        var $href = $(this).attr('href');
        var $anchor = $($href).offset();
        $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: $anchor.top} ,1500);
        return false;
    });
```

For Closing the sidebar It depends on how you made this sidebar.

Comment: i have put the console.log("Here") in your given code and when i click on the sidebar menu item it shows me the Here text in browser console but not doing anything with sidebar or scroll.....@Tasos Fel

Comment: Have you assign the section with correct id ?? for example  <section id="quote"> ?

Comment: <div id="quote" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">......yes i have divs and i assign the divs a specific id

Comment: Is your site online? you have any link ? so i can test it to console?

Comment: https://www.wedesignanything.com/ .....
Please check and sugguest me some solution

Comment: scroller is working on mobile but not closing the sidebar...and on desktop scroll - auto close not working

Comment: I can see that scroll animate works, if i click each item on menu sidebar. if you want to close menu add this :  $('.menu-toggle').trigger('click'); before return false;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166155/discussion-between-ma123456-and-tasos-fel).